# Perl - append text to cell if new cell has text

Tags: perl

My data look as this:

```
20110627 ALPHA BETA GAMMA
 217722 1425 1767 0.654504367955466 0.811585416264778 -0.157081048309312
```

I am using the WriteExcel module (i.e. tab2xls program) of John McNamara :

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel; 
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Workbook;

if (($#ARGV < 1) || ($#ARGV > 2)) {
    die("Usage: tab2xls tabfile.txt newfile.xls\n");
};
open (TABFILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "$ARGV[0]: $!";

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($ARGV[1]);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $row = 0;

while (<TABFILE>) {
    chomp;
    # Split on single space
    my @Fld = split('\s', $_);

    my $col = 0;
    foreach my $token (@Fld) {
        if (looks_like_number($token)) {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
            $col++;
        } else {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
            #$col++;
        }
    }
    $row++;
}
```

I want to do two things: Firstly, keep the text in one cell, and the numbers in separate cells. My code at the moment puts "ALPHA" in one cell, but does not put BETA and GAMMA on this cell (seems like write does not append text if there is already something on the cell, so BETA and GAMMA do not appear at all in the excel file that is produced).

Secondly, in cases like the data I provide, when there is a space in the 2nd line, I want to move the data of the 2nd line in the first line, where each number will be in a separate cell..

Can you help me ? Thanks !

EDIT 1 :

I don't see any answers :D so I thought of changing my code to do the following:

```
foreach my $token (@Fld) {
        if (looks_like_number($token)) {
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
            $col++;
        } else {
            $totalToken = $totalToken." ".$token;
            print "Total token is $totalToken \n";
            $worksheet->write($row, $col, $totalToken);
            $col++;
        }
    }
    $row++;
```

In which case I create a variable $totalToken which appends the text cells.. then the final text cell in the line has all the text cells combined, but I need to get rid of the previous text cells in the line? Any ideas ?

Comment: You are splitting on whitespace when you probably should be splitting on tab.

Comment: If I split on tab it puts every line on one cell so that doesn't work

Comment: The reason you are having these problems is that your data is inconsistent. Can you give more information? Is it tab separated? What else?

Comment: It is not tab separated, this is why I changed split('\t', $_); to split('\s', $_); which if I understand correctly means that they are space-separated. What other info do you need?

Comment: For Edit 1: kill the col++ in the else branch. It might be better to start the $cols variable on 1 in each row, and reserve zero for text? Otherwise you'd have to sort the data in numbers and non-numbers first...

Comment: `\s` is whitespace, which includes both tabs and spaces, and also newlines.